# the right way to use third-party module into angular app that have multiple modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, components

I am using clarity design for angular, and I was wondering what is the best way to inject external module into my app that has multiple modules(submodules).

I tried to use it in app.module.ts to be used in the whole app but it didn't work,

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


// third-party libraries
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ClarityModule } from '@clr/angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ClarityModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LandingComponent } from './pages/landing/landing.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home.routing';

import { ClarityModule } from '@clr/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LandingComponent, LoginComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, HomeRoutingModule, FormsModule, ClarityModule],
  exports: [LandingComponent, LoginComponent]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

x.module.ts for example

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { aComponent} from 'acomponent';
import { bComponent} from 'bcomponent';

import { ClarityModule } from '@clr/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [aComponent, bComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ClarityModule],
  exports: []
})
export class x.module.ts {}

I thought that when I inject clarity module in-app module I could use it in my whole app, but I had to inject it clarity module in every module I use.
so I was wondering if this the right and the only way to use the module.
```

Comment: Add the `ClarityModule` in `exports` array to use it in whole application.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new module file: e.g. clarity.module.ts. and import all your clarity modules there. also make sure you export those modules from that file as well. then you just have to import that module file into your main modules file.

here is an example for angular/material:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
  ],

})
export class AppMaterialModule { }
```

and then in you main module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppMaterialModule } from './app-material.module';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    AppMaterialModule,
  ],

  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

*UsualModuleExports* : components, pipes, directives etc

- Sub Modules(a.k.a Module inside a Module w.r.t routing)
  doesn't inherit modules(*UsualModuleExports*) from it's parent-like module.
- **In Angular every Module(even sub-module) is a closed entity**.
- So, you have to import all modules required by a Module everytime.

Angular `providers` are exception. If a service is provided in App Module it will be available everywhere. So, you see patterns like `Module.forRoot()` in `AppModule` imports(*imports service along with UsualModuleExports*) and `Module.forChild()` in `FeatureModule` imports(*UsualModuleExports*)

To answer your question, **we create a `SharedModule` that exports modules required by all modules in common(FormsModule, ClarityModule etc) and import `SharedModule` in every module.**